# Shopify Integration as Payment Partner - App Rejection Issue

Tags: shopify, integration, payment-gateway

I am integrating with Shopify as Payment Partner. Submitted our app after completing all the mentioned requirements in their documentation. But the app rejected with the below error:

[image]

Do anyone has the idea what kind of consent do Shopify needs?

Comment: Did you do any reading and interpretation of their requirements to ask them for permission first? It seems pretty obvious what is going on here. You did not ask permission first. Try that.

Comment: Yes i have read the requirements. The only thing i got to know about it was revenue share agreement which is already done. I have submitted the app many times previously and we are constantly resolving the reported issues. All of a sudden this issue is reported which is not clear to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just got the response from Shopify Support team. We had missed to submit the signed copy of revenue share agreement to Shopify, which was received many days ago. That was the reason of rejection.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a cursory examination of Payment App process shows you need approval from Shopify before starting, all other things considered.

[image: Payment Apps need review]

Comment: We have already gone through extension review and approval. Then app was submitted and under approval process since long. It was rejected several times due to other technical reasons which are resolved now. Submitted again for review but this time the reported issue is not understandable